# Executing a function when two buttons are clicked in any order

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons in a form, when a click both in any order, I would like to trigger an event.

It is similar to ajax promises:

```
$.when($.ajax({url:"/person"}),$.ajax({url:"/car"}))
.done(function(person,car){
   // do someting with person and car
});
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with buttons' click events ?
Something like

```
$.when($("#button_a").click,$("#button_b").click)
.done(function(ba,bb){
   // do someting with clicks
});
```

Thanks .....

Comment: How are you expecting this to work, given that you can only click one button at a time?

Comment: The same way as ajax do ... they load result in distinct time ...

Comment: Did you mean something like that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/28b0vfsf/  ???

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan *" in any order"* - OP doesn't want to click both at a time... He just wants to do something once both buttons are clicked...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this with event.

```
function DoSomething () 
{
    // do something
}

$("#button_a").click(DoSomething);
$("#button_b").click(DoSomething);
```

Comment: I want both or nothing event, in any order.

Comment: Both button can have separated function that will be execute when the button is pressed. Is it what you want ?

Comment: When I click in both buttons, I want a event to be dispatched. Don't matter the order.

Comment: As T J suggested, if you need to do something when both button are clicked, you need to save the first click somewhere and when both are clicked do something.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a class or data attribute on the button which is clicked, and check whether the other button has the class or not whenever a click happens. For example:

```js
$(".twin").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("clicked");
  if($(".twin").not(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    alert("both clicked");
    $(".twin").removeClass("clicked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="twin">Click1</button>
<button class="twin">Click2</button>
```

---

You can do the same with different handlers as well.

Comment: @MateusBrum What do you mean by *reactive principals*...? Can you  properly explain that in question so that we don't have to waste our time with something that will not help you..?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var promises = [],
    dfd = new $.Deferred(),
    buttons = $("[id$=a], [id$=b]");

buttons.eq(0).on("click.two", function (e) {
    // if `promises` does not contain `e.target` item
    // push item to `promises`
    if (promises[0] !== e.target) {            
      promises.push(e.target);
    }
    two()
});

buttons.eq(1).on("click.two", function (e) {
    // if `promises` does not contain `e.target` item
    // push item to `promises`
    if (promises[0] !== e.target) {            
      promises.push(e.target);
    }
    two()
});

var two = function () {
    // `resolve` `dfd` when `promises.length` === `buttons.length`
    // else `notify` `promises.length`
    return $.when(promises.length === buttons.length 
                  ? dfd.resolve(promises) 
                  : dfd.notify(promises.length))
};

dfd.then(function (p) {
    // do stuff when both `buttons` 
    // clicked in any order
    console.log(p[0], p[1]);
    $(promises).off("click.two")
}, null, function (msg) {
    // notify `promises` length
    console.log(msg)
});
```

```js
var promises = [],
    dfd = new $.Deferred(),
    buttons = $("[id$=a], [id$=b]");

    buttons.eq(0).on("click.two", function (e) {
        // if `promises` does not contain `e.target` item
        // push item to `promises`
        if (promises[0] !== e.target) {            
          promises.push(e.target);
        }
        two()
    });

    buttons.eq(1).on("click.two", function (e) {
        // if `promises` does not contain `e.target` item
        // push item to `promises`
        if (promises[0] !== e.target) {            
          promises.push(e.target);
        }
        two()
    });

var two = function () {
    return $.when(promises.length === buttons.length 
                  ? dfd.resolve(promises) 
                  : dfd.notify(promises.length))
};

dfd.then(function (p) {
    // do stuff when both `buttons` clicked
    // in any order
    console.log(p[0], p[1]);
    $(promises).off("click.two")
}, null, function (msg) {
    // notify `promises` length
    console.log(msg)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_a">a</button><button id="button_b">b</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the click event to the buttons

```
$("#button_a, #button_b").click(function(){
     // do something code
});//click event
```